# PeopleSoft Cobol Directive(s)

Tags: cobol, peoplesoft, microfocus

I have been looking around to find information on COBOL directives that come with vanilla PeopleSoft COBOLs.

I can find information for directives during the [unicode conversion process](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tgbl/task_RunningtheCOBOLConversionUtility-0769ac.html#pt0074c7b_s) but nothing else.

Specifically I am interested in `MVSRND`, what does it do?

Here's an example use:

```
MVSRND 01  WK-HPREC.
MVSRND     02  WK-HIGH-PREC            PIC S9(12)V9(6)         COMP-3.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "MVSRND" (which in the sequence area), is a tag for MVS RANDOM support.

Which might be related to the use of the function random/CEERAN0 or some other api.